# Embarking on a website redevelopment and all developers pushing to move to ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: website-design, asp.net

Our company is going through a website redevelopment / retooling exercise and we are not quite sure which direction to take. We are told that the website was built in ASP classic and that we should be moving to ASP.NET 4.0.

Some developers refuse to do any work in the ASP classic framework citing the advantages of ASP.NET 4.0-- stability, compilation, language support.

We are generally happy with our website as is. There are some kinks in the backend involving forms and there is little integration between the CRM of the website and any content management system.

Does the move from ASP classic to ASP.NET 4.0 give major advantages to the integration between how content is created, and delivered to our customers?

Comment: Given the choice of a new or old (but supported) technology the advantage of going with the new is that if the support for the old is dropped, or it doesn't work with the latest version of an OS then you have to go to the effort of moving to the newer technology when you hadn't planned it, rather than doing it now when you had planned to.

Answer (score 1):

ASP Classic has been outdated for years now, from a developer standpoint and yes, even from your customer's standpoint. Some good points are made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/251070/24875), and that was 4 years ago.